# A Teacher wrote either of words $PARALLELOGRAM$ or $PARALLELOPIPED$

Tags: permutations, combinations

A Teacher wrote either of words $PARALLELOGRAM$ or $PARALLELOPIPED$ on board but due to malfunction of marker words are not properly written and only two consecutive letters $RA$ are visible, then the chance that the written word is $PARALLELOGRAM$ is $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ and $q$ are co-primes. Prove that $p+q=32$

Could someone help me in understanding the line: "only two consecutive letters $RA$ are visible" ? I can't understand this question properly.

Comment: It just means that the only letters that can be seen on the board are R and A in that order.

Comment: It means that you're seeing either XXRAXXXXXXXXX or XXRAXXXXXXXXXX (note the additional X) or XXXXXXXXXXRAX, but you don't know which one of them it is that you're seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counting pairs of consecutive positions as $1-2,\;\; 2-3$ etc,
there are $12$ such positions in **parallelogram**, and $13$ in **parallelopiped**,

thus P(saw RA) $= 2/12$ in parallelogram and $1/13$  in parallelopiped

and P(word "parallelogram" | saw $RA) = \dfrac{2/12}{2/12 + 1/13}=$

Continue....

Comment: Btw, the correct spelling of the second word is PARALLELEPIPED, not that it matters here :)